# Using "asp-for" on a double or decimal property results in a type=text input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-input-tag-helper, `asp-for` should change the input `type` attribute according to the bound property. However, that's not what I'm getting. I've created a new ASP.NET 6 (MVC) webapp and created a model:

```
    public class MyModel
    {
        public double MyProperty { get; set; } = 1.45d;
    }
```

and `Index.cshtml` to

```
@model MyModel;

<div class="text-center">
<input asp-for="MyProperty"/>
</div>
```

When I inspect the element with Firefox's dev tools, I get:

```
<input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field MyProperty must be a number." data-val-required="The MyProperty field is required." id="MyProperty" name="MyProperty" value="">
```

Shouldn't it be `type=number`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms#the-input-tag-helper) does not match with the implementation.

| .NET type | Input type |
| --- | --- |
| Single, Double | type="number" |

The source code on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/7fac52dea79a90143715201d2b1f62289d1ef608/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/InputTagHelper.cs#L47) shows below mapping of data types to input types.

Notice how `Double` is being mapped to `InputType.Text`.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> _defaultInputTypes =
    new(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {
        // ...
        { nameof(Byte), "number" },
        { nameof(SByte), "number" },
        { nameof(Int16), "number" },
        { nameof(UInt16), "number" },
        { nameof(Int32), "number" },
        { nameof(UInt32), "number" },
        { nameof(Int64), "number" },
        { nameof(UInt64), "number" },
        { nameof(Single), InputType.Text.ToString().ToLowerInvariant() },
        { nameof(Double), InputType.Text.ToString().ToLowerInvariant() },
        { nameof(Boolean), InputType.CheckBox.ToString().ToLowerInvariant() },
        { nameof(Decimal), InputType.Text.ToString().ToLowerInvariant() } 
        // ...            
    };
```

---

Do notice that for e.g. a `Double` a `data-val-number` attribute is being rendered as part of the unobtrusive input validation.

```
data-val-number="The field MyProperty must be a number."
```

Comment: Good find! I wonder if this is because those types make use of decimal points...

Comment: Another interesting issue: If I manually set `type=number` the input no longer shows the property value...

Comment: @ASousa looks like setting that one is a no go.